# how to get new height every time element is rendered and remove css style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made this [link to datepicker](https://codepen.io/annib/pen/zRrrLv). If you click the input a jquery datepicker pops up.  When you choose a date, a custom element is added. Firstly, how to remove the added padding when the next and prev button are clicked.  In the jscript I have added that on click of either the previous or next button the padding is empty.

```
$(".ui-datepicker-prev").on("click",function(){
        $(".ui-datepicker").css("padding-left", "");
    });
    $(".ui-datepicker-next").on("click",function(){
        $(".ui-datepicker").css("padding-left", "");
    });
```

But seems it is not working. Secondly how to update the element height dynamically every time the element is rendered.  If you notice when you click the next arrow and the elements height is taller and you choose a date, the height of the added element(in blue) remains the same during the page load. The same case even when window is resized. The height does not update every time elements height is resized.

Answer (score 0):

I only know of one possible solution and that is to change `datepicker-next` with its `padding` to the `right`.

Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**

```
/* padding-left: 328px; */
```

you have used this for padding get rid of it and use dynamic class name something like day_on (where you have padding and big blue area) day_off (where you have p`adding-left:0`)

*Old suggestion - modified

This answer is for problem no 1 - in the css i have commented /* */ code please adjust both for your convinces. it will help you to get rid of the padding/margin 
    .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-title {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        /* margin: 5px; */
    }

```
jquery-ui.css:248
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
    right: 2px;
}
jquery-ui.css:235
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    /* width: 1.8em; */
    /* height: 1.8em; */
}*
```

Comment: Sorry but your suggestion does not work. To accomodate the added new element(one which in blue) I  added a left padding through scripting.  Now, I want to remove the padding when when I click the arrow button.

Comment: /* padding-left: 328px; */ you have used this for padding get rid of it and use dynamic class name something like day_on (where you have padding and big blue area) day_off (where you have padding-left:0)

Comment: in that case entire approch is wrong. you have to use show/hide inserted of padding concept

Comment: i will try your suggestions.

Comment: initially i thought about the pre/next button spacing issue .. i may try in your code later